Coordinates of my mouse are not matching up with my coordinates of my sprite
It was my project to create a duck hunt game in masm615 8086 assembly and in that I have implemented a crosshair that moves with cursor using the INT 33 and I have added a check where on left click of my mouse it checks if the center coordinates of crosshair is in range of any of spirtes coordinates if yes the exit the procedure else continue the loop now the problem in my program is that whenever
I click it it call the checkduckinrange procedure but for some reason that program never returns true (AX=1) even if I click on duck it always returns false (AX=0) I don't know whats happening need help. Pleaseeee

draw proc
    mov ah,0ch
    mov dx, yi      ; y coordinate initial( up down)
y:
    mov cx, xi      ;x coordinate initial (left right)
x:
    mov al,[si]         ; start array
    int 10h
    inc si              ; increment full row  (x axis)
    inc cx
    cmp cx, xf      ; x coordinate final( left right)
    jb x
    inc dx              ; jump to next row
    cmp dx, yf      ; y coordinate final( up down)
    jb y
ret
draw endp


Game1 proc


    mov bp,sp

    mov bullet_count, 0 




    mov al, 13h            
    mov ah, 00h
    int 10H

    call setScene
    mov si, offset  crosshair   ;draw 
                    mov yi, 80
                    mov yf, 94
                    mov xi, 140
                    mov xf, 170
                    call draw



    mov yi, 80
    mov yf, 97
    mov xi, 150
    mov xf, 184
    mov bx,0

    mov bx,xi
    mov temp_xi,bx

    mov bx,xf
    mov temp_xf, bx





    MOV AX,0
    INT 33H

    mov cx, 0
    mov dx, 290
    mov ax,7
    int 33h

    mov cx,0
    mov dx, 186
    mov ax,8
    int 33h

    mov cx,8*4
    mov dx,16*4
    mov ax,0Fh
    int 33h
    
check_time:

    cmp duck_xi, 0
    JL neg_vel
    cmp duck_xf, 140H
    JG neg_vel
    jmp moveit

neg_vel:

neg velocity_x

moveit:
    MOV AX, velocity_x

    mov bx,temp_xi
    mov xi,bx

    mov bx,temp_xf
    mov xf, bx

    ADD xi,AX
    ADD xf,AX

    mov yi, 80
    mov yf, 97

    mov bx,xi
    mov temp_xi,bx

    mov bx,xf
    mov temp_xf, bx
    

    mov bx,0

    call backg
    mov si, offset  duck1
    MOV bx, xi
    mov duck_xi ,bx
    MOV bx, yi
    mov duck_yi, bx
    MOV bx, xf
    mov duck_xf ,bx
    MOV bx, yf
    mov duck_yf, bx

    call draw

    

    MOV AX,3
    INT 33H

    mov si, offset  crosshair   ;draw 

                    CMP CX, 140H
                    JG Nosub
                    SUB CX, 140H
                    nosub:


                    mov yi, DX  
                    mov yf, DX
                    ADD yf, 14
                    mov xi, CX
                    mov xf, CX
                    ADD xf, 30

                    
                    mov ax, yf
                    mov cross_yf, ax
                    sub cross_yf, 9

                    mov ax, xf
                    mov cross_xf, ax
                    sub cross_xf, 17


                    call draw


    cmp BL, 1
    je check_duck    
    jmp draw_cont


check_duck:

    call checkDuckInRange
    CMP AX, 1      
    JE next_round  

draw_cont:
    call setScene
    

jmp check_time

next_round:

mov sp,bp

RET
Game1 ENDP



checkDuckInRange proc
mov bp,sp


    MOV AX, duck_xi
    CMP AX, cross_xf
    JG  notInRange   

    MOV AX, cross_xf
    CMP AX, duck_xf
    JG notInRange   

    MOV AX, duck_yi
    CMP AX, cross_yf
    JL  notInRange   

    MOV AX, cross_yf
    CMP AX, duck_yf
    JG notInRange   

    MOV AX, 1       
    
    RET

notInRange:
    MOV AX, 0
    mov sp,bp
    RET
checkDuckInRange endp


I tried doing different stuff but I don't know why the program never returns true my program have never once return true (AX=1)

Your checkDuckInRange routine is wrong (it has the exact same logic for X and Y - as it should since you are checking exact same thing for both coordinates - except for one JL instead of JG for no reason). You are checking for duck_yi >= cross_yf && cross_yf <= duck_yf, so it would register hit if you'd aim anywhere left of the duck, but never if you aim at the duck.
